# Mapping over deep nested object array JSON file

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, object

I have an nested JSON file that I'm trying to mapping from. As you can see in the JSON example and the return of my console.log below it returns `object` and I can't go further than that. (Please, keep in mind I still working on my JS knowledge...)

I need some help to `map` a nested object/array. One important notice, it's a `map` inside `map`.

Here is the ***GitHub repository***: `https://github.com/clovis-rosa/menu-data-mapping`

To put more context on it, the result should look like the `Footer` of this website `https://www.abstract.com/blog`

Here is an example of JSON data that I'm trying to `map` from:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "title": "Product",
      "id": "001",
      "url": [
        {
          "id": "012",
          "linkName": "How it Works",
          "linkUrl": "how-it-works"
        },
        {
          "id": "013",
          "linkName": "Enterprise",
          "linkUrl": "enterprise"
        },
        {
          "id": "014",
          "linkName": "Pricing",
          "linkUrl": "pricing"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "Features",
      "id": "002",
      "url": [
        {
          "id": "022",
          "linkName": "Version Control",
          "linkUrl": "version-control"
        },
        {
          "id": "023",
          "linkName": "Design Collaboration",
          "linkUrl": "design-collaboration"
        },
        {
          "id": "024",
          "linkName": "Developer Handoff",
          "linkUrl": "developer-handoff"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "Resources",
      "id": "003",
      "url": [
        {
          "id": "032",
          "linkName": "Getting Started",
          "linkUrl": "getting-started"
        },
        {
          "id": "033",
          "linkName": "Blog",
          "linkUrl": "blog"
        },
        {
          "id": "034",
          "linkName": "Books",
          "linkUrl": "books"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "Community",
      "id": "004",
      "url": [
        {
          "id": "042",
          "linkName": "Twitter",
          "linkUrl": "twitter"
        },
        {
          "id": "043",
          "linkName": "LinkedIn",
          "linkUrl": "linkedin"
        },
        {
          "id": "044",
          "linkName": "Facebook",
          "linkUrl": "facebook"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "Company",
      "id": "005",
      "url": [
        {
          "id": "052",
          "linkName": "About us",
          "linkUrl": "about-us"
        },
        {
          "id": "053",
          "linkName": "Careers",
          "linkUrl": "careers"
        },
        {
          "id": "054",
          "linkName": "Legal",
          "linkUrl": "legal"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

He is my component where I'm trying to `map` the data:

```
export default function Footer() {
  const allFooterList = UseFooterDataQuery().allDataJson.edges

  return (
    <FooterSection>
      <FooterContainer>
        {allFooterList.map(({ node }) => {
          console.log(node, `====================> NODE`)
          return (
            <FooterWrap key={node.id}>
              <h3>{node.title}</h3>
              {node.data.map(data => {
                console.log(data, `====================> DATA`)
                return (
                  <ul key={data.id}>
                    <li>
                      <Link to={`/${data.linkUrl}`}>{data.linkName}</Link>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                )
              })}
            </FooterWrap>
          )
        })}
      </FooterContainer>
      <FooterContainer>
        <p>© {new Date().getFullYear()}</p>
        <p>Built with Gatsby</p>
      </FooterContainer>
    </FooterSection>
  )
}
```

Here is the result of my console.log. Right now I cant' go further than that to get inside de object:

```
Object { id: "35707249-168b-511c-83a0-03724efc2108", data: (5) […] } ====================> NODE
Object { id: "001", title: "Product", url: (7) […] } ====================> DATA
Object { id: "002", title: "Features", url: (3) […] } ====================> DATA
Object { id: "003", title: "Resources", url: (7) […] } ====================> DATA
Object { id: "004", title: "Community", url: (5) […] } ====================> DATA
Object { id: "005", title: "Company", url: (3) […] } ====================> DATA
```

Comment: It will help if you explain in plain terms what you are trying to "map" as an implementation with logical errors cannot self-explain

Comment: @GetSet thanks for the advice!

Comment: maybe  `Object.entries()` and `Object.keys()` is what you looking for

Comment: Thanks for the comment @gugateider. I already tried and didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on right track, kudos to you! here is some help, you just needed to go one more nested loop further with accessing the appropriate map object and keys.

https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-mountain-z4pi9?file=/src/App.js

Here I have added the code and sample output you will able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

After destructuring the first node and it worked! Here the final result:

```
  return (
    <footer>
      <nav>
        {allFooterList.map(({ node }) => {
          return (
            <div key={node.id}>
              {node.data.map(data => {
                return (
                  <div key={data.id}>
                    <h3>{data.title}</h3>
                    {data.url.map(url => {
                      return (
                        <ul key={url.id}>
                          <li>
                            <Link to={`/${url.linkUrl}`}>{url.linkName}</Link>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                      )
                    })}
                  </div>
                )
              })}
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </nav>
    </footer>
  )
}
```

Thank you very much Abhijeet Abnave!